# Org-mode: Hide link's URL ([[URL][TITLE]]) in specific file

Tags: org-mode

I'm seeking for a file-local options (`#+OPTIONS:`) or something similar to auto set link display (See `M-x org-toggle-link-display` or variable `org-link-descriptive`).

I've tried `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line` provided by Emacs itself but seems doesn't work for org-mode and it's ugly.

Only found this: https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html but seems nothing is what I want......

Comment: You can use `add-file-local-variable` (that is, not `-prop-line`), and it goes in end of your file.

Comment: You can also make it into a separate section in your Org mode file, and tag it `noexport` so that it never gets exported. And you can fold the heading so you don't see (most of) it.

Comment: @gusbrs In fact, I found prop-line indeedly changed the variable locally, but org-mode itself doesn't read the local value when using org-mode... I also found this https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg134934.html but no more reply on this...

Comment: @kuanyui That is true! I've made a bug report about it, and will see if I can come up with a temporary workaround.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for reporting... I hate mailing list and not good at the use it, so whenever encounter a project which still insists in using this terrible outdated technology for bug reporting, I usually feel upset and give up to write any bug report in the end.

Comment: Well, you are missing a very nice community of  people who love Org mode and ask and answer questions, suggest code changes, report bugs and do a whole lot more than a bug reporting system does. So if you change your mind, do join and lurk for a bit. If you find you don't like it, you can drop it. But I think there is a good chance you'll be hooked. As for bug reports, do `M-x org-submit-bug-report`, add a description of the bug and hit `Send`. You can then watch its progress (if any - there are no guarantees) at https://updates.orgmode.org/

Comment: @NickD Well said. :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, what you reported in the comments, that Org does not seem to honor the file-local-variable setting of `org-link-descriptive` appears to be a bug, and I've reported it to Org (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2021-10/msg00924.html).

In the meantime, a workaround is to put the following in your init file:

```
(defun my/fix-org-link-descriptive-local ()
  (if org-link-descriptive (remove-from-invisibility-spec '(org-link))
    (add-to-invisibility-spec '(org-link)))
  (org-restart-font-lock))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my/fix-org-link-descriptive-local)
```

And don't forget to follow up on the bug report to remove it, when it gets fixed upstream.

With that in hand, adding the variable with `M-x add-file-local-variable` should work as expected, and place the corresponding setup at the end of your file.

@NickD's tip to make a heading for local variables is a good one to, to which I myself resort when setting file local variables with Org: it helps the visuals, and also makes some structural editing cleaner/safer.  So, after setting the variable, the end of your file could look like:

```
* Local Variables                                                  :noexport:

# Local Variables:
# org-link-descriptive: nil
# End:
```

And which, normally, would just get folded, so you just see the heading.